# beep sound for webview

Tags: android

I am working on the webview . I am fetching some graph values from the database and on the basis of these values there is a beep in webpage. In the explore  its works fine for me but when i am calling this page in webview the other things are fine but there is no beep sound . 
 Please guide . I am calling sound in the following way

```
    if($info['sensor_a']<=10)
    {echo"" ;
$file='beep.wav';
echo "<embed src =\"$file\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
    }
    ?></span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, there are several steps:

If beep.wav is stored locally, you must use a ContentProvider in order to fetch the file.

You then have to embed a javascript hook for a callback to the Android system.

I hope this helps, please check out the documentation for specific examples of these two functions.